# How to add to slider images from array(for example local images or from websites)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, bootstrap-slider

I want to make this HTML dynamically: images and this "dots" 
and I want to load them from JavaScript Array. help please!

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
    <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li> 
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li> 
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li> 
    </ol> 

<div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <div class="item active"> 
        <img src="~/Content/img/sl1.jpg" width="100%" /> 
    </div> 

    <div class="item"> 
        <img src="~/Content/img/sl2.jpg" width="100%" /> 
    </div> 

    <div class="item"> 
        <img src="~/Content/img/3sl.jpg" width="100%" /> 
    </div> 
</div> 

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> 
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> 
</a> 
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> 
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span> 
</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. The accepted format for a question is that you have a problem that you have attempted to solve that you cannot. You must provide evidence of the attempt(this helps illustrate the problem) so that you, and others in the future, can benefit from any answer given.

Comment: Your question is not related to the specific bootstrap slider library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry try this  :

```
   <script language='javascript'>
    var img = ['~/Content/img/sl1.jpg', '~/Content/img/sl2.jpg',  '~/Content/img/sl3.jpg'];

  function viewImage(id, next) {
    let imgElement = document.getElementById(id);

    let index = imgElement.getAttribute('index');
        if (typeof index === 'undefined') {
        index = 0;
    }

    if(next === 'next') {
        index++;
      if (index == img.length) index = 0;
    }
    else{
        index--;
      if (index < 0) index = img.length - 1;
    }

    imgElement.setAttribute('index', index);
    imgElement.src = img[index];
  }

</script>



<div>
  <button onclick="viewImage('image','previous')">PREVIOUS
  </button>
  <button onclick="viewImage('image','next')">NEXT
  </button>
</div>

<div>
  <img id="image" src=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to create an array in js, for example var images = [
    img1,img2,img3]; and load them to slider!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using bootstrap 4 and jquery

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"></div>

    <script>
    var images = ['//lorempixel.com/300/250/food/4/','//lorempixel.com/300/250/food/2/','//lorempixel.com/300/250/food/3/'];
    buildcarousel("carouselExampleIndicators", images)
    function buildcarousel(id,images){
      var html = $("#"+id).append('<ol class="carousel-indicators"></ol><div class="carousel-inner"></div><a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#'+id+'" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control-next" href="#'+id+'" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');
      let indicators = html.find('.carousel-indicators');
      let carousel = html.find('.carousel-inner')
      images.forEach((e,i)=>{
        var activeclass = i == 0 ? "active":"";
        indicators.append('<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="'+i+'" class="'+activeclass+'"></li>');
        carousel.append('<div class="carousel-item '+activeclass+'"><img class="d-block w-100" src="'+e+'" alt="First slide"></div>');
      })
    }
    </script>
```

Demo Link: https://codepen.io/manab_27/pen/pMjROY